# Sql Join between two tables with a group by

Tags: sql, oracle

I am extremely new to SQL and I have been working on this problem for hours and I am so close but not quite there:

Three tables

### Category

cid
cname

**Product**

```
pid
cid
pname
brand
price
```

**Review**

```
rid
userid
pid
rdate
score rcomment
```

I am trying to

- Return the product name and average score.
- Return the names of product under the category TV and with average rating above 4.0

1:

```
select avg(score), review.pid
from review
join product
on review.pid = product.pid
group by review.pid;
```

2:

```
select * from product
join review
on product.pid = review.pid
where cid ='1';
```

Here is a fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a6b30/1

Comment: Does your data also have a third table where cid=1 and cname='TV'? If so, please edit your question (do not answer in a Comment!) so that future readers of your question will see the full problem statement in one place. Also, why is cid '1' and not 1 (meaning, why is it a string with one character, the digit 1, and not simply the number 1)? That is unusual.

Comment: done, and I am not sure, that's the way I was taught but you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can add the `pname` to your `GROUP BY` clause and then to your `SELECT` clause. `pid` is unique for each product so it does not affecting the query at all, but let you add the name to your results.

   ```
   select avg(review.score), product.pname
   from review
   join product
   on review.pid = product.pid
   group by product.pname;
   ```
2. In the following query I use a subquery to select only items with average score >= 4 using `HAVING` clause. Then I select only `pid` that appear in the subquery's result and adding the `cid='1'` part.

   ```
   select product.pname
   from product
   join review
   on product.pid = review.pid
   where cid ='1'
   and pid IN (SELECT pid FROM review GROUP BY pid HAVING AVG(score) >= 4);
   ```

Comment: #1 (still returns pid, )# 2 is failing in the fiddle (column ambiguously defined)

Comment: @user2402107 It was due to the use of `select *`. It's supposed to work now.

Comment: what about subqueries like this one: Return the name of the laptop with the lowest weight... I am updating to show my current code for this

Comment: Basically, you should have a subquery that selects the `pid` of that category with `MIN(price)` and then, in the main query, have something like `WHERE pid = (SUBQUERY)`.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, it should be pretty similar to query #2. Just replace the subquery with one like `SELECT pid FROM review INNER JOIN product USING (pid) WHERE cid='2' AND price = (SELECT MIN(price) FROM product WHERE cid='2')` (assuming that laptops are category 2).

Comment: actually this is not right, I am testing this out in the fiddle and after modifying myself and its not returning it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124155/discussion-between-user2402107-and-neria-nachum).

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
select  p.pname, avg(r.score) 
from review r
join product p
on p.pid = r.pid
group by p.pname;
```

2.
 The following query returns the ids and the  names of product under the category TV and with average score above 4.0

```
   select  p.pname,  avg(r.score)
    from 
        category c
    join product p on p.cid = c.cid 
    join review r  on r.pid = p.pid
    where c.cname = 'TV'
    group by 
      p.pname
    having  avg(r.score) > 4 ;
```

Comment: is there a way not to have the pid in the return?

Comment: This may work since the name may be unique (two different TV's with different pid may not have the same name), but that is not guaranteed. So the grouping should still be by p.pid, not by p.pname. If there are duplicate names (for different pid's), they should still appear as duplicate in the output. (Which points out a flaw in the request itself: if names may be the same for different pid's, the pid should, in fact, be included in the output). Otherwise why is there a pid separate from pname, and why isn't pname itself the primary key?